# How remove white space from result data in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have trying to remove white space in binding control.How to remove whitespace?

```
 this.addressInfo.patchValue({
   street: result.data['street'],
   houseNumber: result.data['houseNo'],
   city: result.data['city'],
   country: result.data['country'],
   zipCode: result.data['postalCode']
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find out simple solution. Only need to use .trim() key word.

```
 this.addressInfo.patchValue({
                        street: result.data['street'].trim(),
                        houseNumber: result.data['houseNo'].trim(),
                        city: result.data['city'].trim(),
                        country: result.data['country'].trim(),
                        zipCode: result.data['postalCode'].trim()
                    });
```

Comment: Use trim() keywords before check value of data (result.data['street']) not blank other wise throw exception.